# C# inheritance and interfaces confusion

Tags: c#, inheritance

I am trying to use fakes for EF 4.1 DataContext to test the repository without testing the database ( due to a deployment issue)

I am doing something like this

```
public interface IEmployeeContext
{
    IDbSet<Department> Departments { get; }
    IDbSet<Employee> Employees { get; }
    int SaveChanges();
}

public class EmployeeContext : DbContext, IEmployeeContext
{
    public IDbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
    public IDbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}

public class FakeEmployeeContext : IEmployeeContext
{
    public IDbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
    public IDbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    public FakeEmployeeContext ()
    {
        Departments = new FakeDbSet<Department>();
        Employees = new FakeDbSet<Employee>();
    }
}
```

which works great most of the time but my problem is that sometimes in my code i use things like :

```
context.Entry(department).State  = EntityState.Modified;
```

and it complains that

'IEmployeeContext' does not contain a definition for 'Entry'

I cannot seem to comprehend what i need to change in the pattern to allow me access to the context.Entry and context.Database sections

Comment: Can you show the code for the declaration of `context`?

Comment: Is this a casting related problem? `IEmployeeContext` does not define a `Entry` attribute/function but instead its defined in the `DbContext` class. `((IEmployeeContext)context).Entry(department).State ..` might solve your problem.

Comment: Seems like you want your FakeEmployeeContext to also inherit from DbContext, since EmployeeContext does

Comment: The Declaration of EmployeeContext is the second class...

Comment: Casting as IEmployeeContext wouldnt help its already resolving to that .. and Casting to EmployeeContext would defeat the purpose of a n interface

Comment: public class FakeEmployeeContext : DbContext, IEmployeeContext still gives me the error because the enviroment cannot knwo that all classes that Inherit from IEmployeeContext also  Inherit from DbContext

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting that specific error is because `IEmployeeContext` doesn't contain a method called `Entry`.

`Entry` is a member of `DbContext`.

Comment: If i make an Entry method part of the IEmployeeContext then I need to impliment it in in both EmployeeContext and FakeEmployeeContext and it is already implimented in EmployeeContext

Comment: Right, that method is coming from `DbContext`. A possible solution is to make your fake class inherit `DbContext`, although I haven't done enough with EF to be able to tell you if that will be of any use to you or not.

Comment: Just did some digging on this, and worst case, you can hide the `Entry` method from DbContext for the purposes of your fake employee context. It should, I believe, look like: `public new DbEntityEntry<TEntity> Entry<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity: class {}`